# Where can I ask about frozen badgers?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to ask the following question, which *may* be suitable for pets or politics, but I'm not really sure either way – or if it’s on-topic anywhere?

> ### Why does Peterborough City Council freeze badgers?
>
> Peterborough City Council has released [the amount of animals](http://data.peterborough.gov.uk/View/environmental-protection-animal-welfare/animals-frozen-including-type-and-quantity) they freeze each year as part of an open data initiative. For 2013 this includes 101 cats, 4 dogs, 7 rodents and 6 badgers.
>
> I've found [an article in the Argus](http://www.theargus.co.uk/news/10531729.Worthing_and_Adur_councils_freeze_100_cats_and_dogs_over_last_two_years/), *"Worthing and Adur councils freeze 100 cats and dogs over the last two years"*, which states that:
>
> > Pets killed on the roads are being stored in freezers by councils in case their owners want to reclaim their dead animals.
>
> This seems reasonable(ish) but why then does it apply to foxes, rodents, birds, deer, badgers, hedgehogs and "other".
>
> What is the purpose of freezing these animals?

Where would this question be on-topic?

Comment: Wait, _what_???

Comment: Not sure where that's ontopic, but I hope they are [killed with chloroform or a carbon dioxide chamber before freezing](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/33300/6836).

Comment: It would be appropriate at the next Peterborough City Council meeting.  There's little chance you will find a definitive answer to this anywhere else.\

Comment: I have this conjecture that everything outside the world of computers and that is not yet on-topic on another Stack Exchange, can be asked on Travel, if cleverly packaged. I have no found the time and questions yet to verify this, but your question seems quite fit for this.

Comment: Just let it go.

Comment: Did you *have* to create a badgers tag? Really?

Comment: Quoting Obelix from "Asterix & Obelix": "These americans are crazy"

Comment: @MyNameIsRui [Peterborough](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterborough)... though the `data.peterborough.gov.uk` url should be a hint there too.

Comment: Pretty sure asking this on Pets will not go all that well, as the part you are really asking about is about the non-pet animals, which makes it off topic.

Comment: @MichaelT [Let it go](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=moSFlvxnbgk)?

Comment: @Andy Let it go, let it go. Can't keep them in the fridge anymore.  Let it go, let it go. When they thaw, you'll be out the door. / I don't care what they're going to say, let the reports pile on, the paperwork never bothered me anyway!

Comment: [badgers don't care](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=4r7wHMg5Yjg "obligatory Honey Badger Don't Care") about where it's on-topic

Comment: @MichaelT Made me LOL.

Comment: As a pets mod *not* on topic for us. I do wonder if its cost - they get 'enough' dead critters and have them disposed at once.

Answer (score 4):

The heart of the question has to do with this City Council's policy. Thusly, [**Politics.SE**](https://politics.stackexchange.com/) seems the right place for such a question.
From [their 'Asking' page](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Central to the idea of this site are the nuts and bolts of policies introduced by governments, presumably for the welfare of their citizens.

> Questions seeking to understand the rules and processes by which policy is made in various legislatures or ruling bodies (inside and outside of the United States!) are wholly on topic

You might want to adapt your question a little to that site, by rephrasing "*What is the purpose of freezing these animals?*" to "*What is the reason for this policy?*", or something of that nature.